# Question's last activity by a different user

Tags: discussion, last-activity

In my Activity page's questions section, I see a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28990499/2451726)'s last modified/answered by a user named "Abhishek".

But seeing the question, he didn't involve in any activity of the question [Did not answer or edit the question].

How this is possible?

Is he post an answer and removed it later, or is there any other possibility?

> [image: LastModifiedBy]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see it so it probably he posted an answer that would soon be deleted quickly, either by him or reasons of moderation. We don't enough rep to see deleted posts, thus we can't see the last change, which was an added deleted answer.

If he edited anything, his name should show up below the, "Edited apr 13..." line. None of the posts do, so editing is out of the question. The only last option is answering. He first answered but might have been very low quality so it could have been deleted by himself of through user who can delete posts.

Comment: `probably he posted an answer that would soon be deleted quickly` This was what happened here.

Comment: I agree with [a deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29608404)